# Is there a clean way to exclude one project in a solution from the commit/push?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-c++

I made a Visual Studio solution with two projects: a static C++ library and an executable console application to test it. I want to use Git and Github only for the library project, but if I put the other project inside the gitignore the .sln file will still give me some trouble since it references the executable project, whenever I pull from any machine. I'd like to keep a .sln file in the repository since it helps with configuration. Should I just commit/push it once and then put it in the gitignore once I create the executable project?

Comment: How about putting a template `.sln` file in your Git repo that you copy and modify whenever you do a new clone? And then put the real `.sln` file in `.gitignore`. If you commit your real file, adding it to `.gitignore` later will have no effet, since that mechanism only works for files that are not currently tracked.

Comment: @joanis by "new clone" you mean "new push"? Else I think I don't understand what you mean, but maybe it's just my poor english. If I understood correctly though this sounds like a good idea, yet it feels like there should be some simpler solution to this problem. Thank you for your time anyway :)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I entirely understand your situation either, but if I understood correctly, you're going to make regular changes to that .sln file, which you don't want to commit. So on each push, you're just ignoring those changes. But when a new developer starts working on the project and needs to setup their .sln file, they would clone the repo, and copy the template to the real file. So that's what I mean by "new clone".